# Simplification $F=\frac{\sin x(1-\sin x)(2+\sin x)(1+\sin x-\cos x)}{2\left[y\left(4-\sin^{2}x-2(1+\cos x)(1+\sin x)\right)+\sin^{2}x\right]}$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any way of further simplification of this trigonometric function?

$$F=\frac{\sin x(1-\sin x)(2+\sin x)(1+\sin x-\cos x)}{2\left[y\left(4-\sin^{2}x-2(1+\cos x)(1+\sin x)\right)+\sin^{2}x\right]},$$
or, its square $F^2$?

After many attempts, I am a little skeptical... However, thanks for your help...

Comment: the two term in Numerator can be simplified into: (1-sinx)*(1+sinx-cosx)=(1-sinx)*(1+sinx)-(1-sinx)*cosx=cosx(cosx+1-sinx)

Comment: @Wz: Thanks. However, I am still not able to factorize the denominator.